# How do I show a selected date data from a SQL Server database in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagrid

How do I show a selected date data from a SQL Server database in a `DataGridView`?

I tried but that shows all data from database.

Here is the code which triggers when I click the button to show

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select currDate,WtrNm,Type,No from WtrTblAllot", con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
dgvWtrAllot.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have a `WHERE` clause in your query its very obvious that it will fetch all data from the database.

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select currDate,WtrNm,Type,No
                                        from WtrTblAllot", con);
```

Add [WHERE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) clause to your query if you want to fetch only specific records form the database table.

Answer (score 0):

Use your selected date in WHERE clause as @Coder says...

```
Date selectedDate = Date.Now;
String query = "SELECT currDate,WtrNm,Type,No FROM WtrTblAllot WHERE currDate = @SelectedDate";
SqlComman command = New SqlCommand(query, con);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectedDate", selectedDate);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
dgvWtrAllot.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

When adding some values inside of query, then better practice is using of parameters...